# UserManager.Create(user, password) thowing EntityValidationError saying Id is required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Anybody know why `UserManager.Create(user, password);` might be throwing `EntityValidationError` saying `Id` is required.

Could it have something to do with my `UserManager`.  It is setup like this:

```
public class MyAppDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public static MyAppDb Create()
    {
        return new MyAppDb();
    }

    public MyAppDb()
        : base("MyAppDb")
    {
    }
}


public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(MyAppDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
}
```

And in the controller like this:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public AccountController()
        : this(new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new MyAppDb())))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        UserManager.PasswordValidator = (IIdentityValidator<string>)new MinimumLengthValidator(8);
        UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false, RequireUniqueEmail = true };
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager { get; private set; }

    ...
}
```

`ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationRole`, `ApplicationUserLogin`, `ApplicationUserRole`, and `ApplicationUserClaim` all inherit from the Identity classes respectively.

Anyone see anything wrong?  I was able to register users (`UserManager.Create())` before I created all the custom Identity classes without the `Id` issue.

**UPDATE:** It seems specifying `string` for the Key has broken the auto-generated Key in the database context. That is my best guess. It now is looking for me to set the `Id`. I don't want to, I want it to work the way it did before I created the custom fields on the `User`.

Comment: For the id-issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721011/aspnet-identity-custom-user-and-custom-role-should-be-simple-what-am-i-missing/22746674#22746674

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears specifying `string` tells the `UserStore` that you will provide the `Id`.  This issue went away when I solved the following issue [Is there a way to create a custom User and Role without specifying the TKey on IdenitityUser, IdentityRole, and IdentityDbContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724938/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-custom-user-and-role-without-specifying-the-tkey-on-I)

-OR-

Just give it an `id` like this: `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can try is to add the id on a parameterless constructor of ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser :  IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>, IUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
        : base()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Method Create() requires ID.

I just inherited IdentityUser like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  // Rest of your implmentation...
}
```

When I create new instance of ApplicationUser it will contain ID.

```
public static ApplicationUser GetUser(this UserViewModel model)
    {
        var applicationUser = new ApplicationUser
        {
            DisplayName = model.DisplayName,
            Email = model.Email,
            EmailConfirmed = model.EmailConfirmed,
            UserName = model.UserName,
            Description = model.Description,
            LastSignOn = model.LastSignOn
        };

        return applicationUser;
    }
```

GetUser() method will convert UserViewModel which doesn't have ID ApplicationUser with populated ID.