# Why am I getting an IdentityRole error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Using Identity 2.0 After registering a user, the user is created in the database, there is code in the Account controller to create an identity and sign the user in.  This is when I get the error.  Here is the code producing the error:

```
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

And here is the error:

> The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

My Model looks like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string ProperName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyAppDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
    {
        public MyAppDb()
            : base("MyAppDb")
        {
        }
    }
}
```

My `UserManager` is created like this in the Account controller:

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public AccountController()
        {
        }

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyAppDb()));
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've spent a lot of time on this issue and posted many questions to get to the bottom of it.  I sure hope this information helps other folks.

Basically, customizing the `User` is easy and there are several examples available. However, customizing the `Role` is problematic and the only examples I found were customized far beyond what comes "out of the box" and I was able to get one working after resolving an `Id` issue. The issue in that case was that I had to create the `Id` myself. Here is that issue: [UserManager.Create(user, password) thowing EntityValidationError saying Id is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22698744/usermanager-createuser-password-thowing-entityvalidationerror-saying-id-is-re)

So in simple examples, notice when you are just customizing the `User` your `DbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext` and you just provide the `IdentityUser`, in my case it was called `ApplicationUser` and looked like this `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. Also notice that the `UserManager` and `UserStore` is provided the `IdentityUser` as well, and in most examples looks like this `new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))`

**But once you customize your `Role`** you need to pass everything, including the key type `TKey` of the `Id` fields. Mine looks like this `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>` because I only customized the `User` and `Role`.

But you aren't done yet, because the regular `UserManager` doesn't understand anymore. *I think this is something the Identity folks could/should fix, but I digress.* So I had to implement my own `UserStore` and `UserManager` and notice (and this is the part that tripped me up) **you have to provide the `KType`** here too or instantiating your custom `UserManager` will give you a compile-time error:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(MyAppDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
}
```

And instantiate the `UserManager` in the Account controller like this `new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new MyAppDb()))`:

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new MyAppDb()));
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I think every developer knows that after lots of research in the end the solution can look ridiculously simple, but would you mind expanding a little on what brought you to this point?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the answer and give my best explanation to what I believe is happening.

Comment: Hi @SeanNewcome, When I try to implement your solution, what do I change my user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager); to?